# Vue: communicating parameters from app to component and back, using computed properties

Tags: vue.js

Sorry for the beginner question (I'm fairly sure this will be a duplicate, but I actually can't figure out what terms to use in order to find it). I just started with Vue.

I am just getting started with Vue, and following this course (https://www.vuemastery.com/courses/intro-to-vue-js/communicating-events). In this problem, there is (and here I don't know the term, so I'm going to go with...) *app-level* data parameter called `cart`. `cart` is an array which holds the `id` of each item a user has added to cart.

The problem tells us to add a button to remove items from the cart.

I ran into problems trying to create a computed property, which would allow me to hide the "remove" button in the event the selected item is not in the cart (eg. `

1. Communicating data from the app-level (the `cart` array), to the component-level (to a computed property in the `product` component), so that I could use something like `:hidden="!inCart"` on the "Remove from Cart" button, which is itself defined in the component. `inCart` would be a computed value here.
2. Communicating the selected product from the component to the app-level, computing `inCart` at the app level, then using the computed value at the component-level.

Either way, I can't seem to figure out how to do this in the way I would want to, which would look something like how `v-bind` operates. Namely, I think I may be able to hack together a solution using methods (which I believe have to be triggered by certain events), but I don't understand how I might go about this using built-in functionality such that the value of `inCart` is dynamically auto-computed.

Maybe there would be an answer to this in the next few courses, but I don't see us covering that in the intro material. Sorry for the neophyte question. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vue the way you communicate "state" from higher-level objects to lower-level objects is through props.

So, assuming your app looks something like...

```
<MyApp>
  <MyShoppingPageWithItems>
    <MyItem></MyItem>
    <MyItem></MyItem>
  <MyShoppingPageWithItems>
</MyApp>
```

You need to pass the cart object down as a prop.

So in your `MyShoppingPageWithItems` template, you'll have something like...

```
<template>
  <div>
    <MyItem v-for="item in items" :item=item :cart="cart"?
    </MyItem>
  </div>
</template>
```

And in your item template...

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      {{item.name}}
    </div>
    <div v-if="cart.includes(item.id)">
      Remove button or whatever
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Not that the `.includes()` method is a native JavaScript method, which you can read more about [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes_array.asp).

**Edit**

To reference a prop in a computed property (or anywhere else in a Vue component), just refer to this.propName, [as demonstrated here in the Vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html).

So, if you want to create a computed property, you can do the following:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      {{item.name}}
    </div>
    <div v-if="isInCart">
      Remove button or whatever
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
   export default {
     props: ['cart', 'item'],
     computed: {
       isInCart() {
         return this.cart.includes(this.item.id)
       }
     }
   }
</script>
```

Note that the formula is the exact same as above, but just includes `this.` for cart and item. In templates, the `this.` is implied when referring to props, data, and computed properties.

Comment: So maybe what I'm missing is how you communicate props to computed values? How would you compute `inCart` as a computed value, by passing down the `cart` array as a prop? Or would I have to compute it at the app-level, and then pass it down? In that case, I have to `$emit` the particular product?

Comment: Edited above. There is no emitting going on, because nothing is changing / no events are happening. You are simply inspecting the state, and the best place to inspect the state of an Item is in an Item component.

Comment: Another way to think about it is not "the props communicate to computed values". The computed values simply look at the props of the object they're in. Props are just there.

Comment: So if I understand, it's sort of like each higher-level component sets environment variables (aka props) for the lower-level components? Or maybe a better analogy is inherited class attributes in another programming language, where lower-level components are subclasses?

Also - the app-level <MyApp> data variables are just the same as any other component's data?

Comment: I think I'd lean into the "environment variable" metaphor more than the "inherited attributes" metaphor, but I see where you're coming from with both. The reason for my hesitance in the "inherited attributes" metaphor is that a child component only "inherits" the explicit props passed down from the parent, whereas in my (brief) experience in, say, Ruby, the subclass inherits everything.

Comment: But YES! You're definitely thinking about it the right way. :)

Comment: And finally, MyApp is just a component like any other component. So its data is just component data, that can be passed down as props to whomever. The only think "special" about your top-level component is it can be accessed from children using `this.$root`, but it's kind of an anti-pattern. See the docs: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-the-Root-Instance